# iOS NSTextAttachment image not showing

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

NSTextAttachment lock image cut off at the edge but when the line does not breaks at the edge then the lock icon can be seen. I want the icon to move to the next line like a word move to the next line.

Here are the example:

```
    NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"];
    NSString *stringHeadline = @"This is a example sample sentence. Why I do";
    NSAttributedString *attachmentLock = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
    NSAttributedString *myText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringHeadline];
    NSMutableAttributedString *lockString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:myText];

    [lockString appendAttributedString:attachmentLock];
    lblHeadline.attributedText = lockString;
    [lblHeadline sizeToFit];
```

[image]

[image: Lock icon gone missing when the text near the edge.]

Lock icon gone missing when the text near the edge.

Comment: in top image also text is till the end but it shows image..

Comment: @iDev The image does not show.

Comment: but if you see the text both texts are same

Comment: @iDev The texts are not the same. I added a bit more words so that the text does not stop at the edges thus image is showing.

Comment: remove `sizeToFit()` and change the height

Comment: My label height is dynamic and will expand if the headline sentence is long. Remove sizeToFit will make it static.

Comment: are you setting any constraints to label ?

Answer (score 7):

Just append a space after your NSTextAttachment. Otherwise the NSTextAttachment does not change to a new line like a normal text does when there's not enough space for it. I believe this's a bug of Apple.

Your code should likes like this:

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"];
NSString *stringHeadline = @"This is a example sample sentence. Why I do";
NSAttributedString *attachmentLock = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
NSAttributedString *myText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringHeadline];
NSMutableAttributedString *lockString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:myText];

[lockString appendAttributedString:attachmentLock];
/** 
 * Here I'm adding a space after NSTextAttachment just to make sure that
 * the NSTextAttachment will auto change to next line like normal text does.
 * Otherwise the NSTextAttachment does not move to the new line.
 */
[lockString appendAttributedString: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "]];
lblHeadline.attributedText = lockString;
[lblHeadline sizeToFit];
```

Check out more about my solution by checking my Post [Attach Stars to the End of a UILabel](http://zhuhuihuihui.github.io/blog/2015/02/14/attach-stars-to-the-end-of-a-uilabel/).

Comment: I had a similar bug where the text attachment would disappear if it was close to the edge. Adding a space triggered a new line.

Comment: Thank you, I've got the same problem and your solution saved me perhaps a couple of hours!